# setuid must be string getting error when trying to deploy my node js app to google cloud platform

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform, setuid

I m getting this error when I try to deploy it to google cloud platform.
I m using Redis NODEjs

[image: Setuid must be string]
Error msg:

```
Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 401 - "{\"error\":\"Something strange occurred. Please contact the app owners.\",\"link\":null,\"developer message\":\"No user credentials were provided.\",\"error_code\":8003}" 
4:52:44 PM sync.1 | at new StatusCodeError (E:\DOwn\Compressed\multiprocess-master\node_modules\request-promise\lib\errors.js:32:15) 
4:52:44 PM sync.1 | at Request.RP$callback [as _callback]
```

Comment: It seems you nodejs need read something for ENV , but you don't have setup .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But brother it needs for environment variables that are working fine. I can share the code with you. How I can get rid of this error. I m stuck.

Comment: You should paste this log /root/.npm/_logs/2019-02-23T19_53_56_311Z-debug.log. for more information

Comment: Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 401 - "{\"error\":\"Something strange occurred. Please contact the app owners.\",\"link\":null,\"developer message\":\"No user credentials were provided.\",\"error_code\":8003}" 4:52:44 PM sync.1 | at new StatusCodeError (E:\DOwn\Compressed\multiprocess-master\node_modules\request-promise\lib\errors.js:32:15) 4:52:44 PM sync.1 | at Request.RP$callback [as _callback]